# Android loop service every 5 seconds and boot on startup

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have the code below and I want to loop this every 5 seconds. I have tried to use broadcastreceiver and alarm manager but without success . I want my service to loop for 5 times and after that stop permanently .This is the second question I post . Please somebody help me to fix the code, I am stacked on my mac for 2 days. Any help will be appreciated.

Code to loop every 5 seconds

```
File key = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"newfile"+Math.random()+".txt");
try {
    key.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

InfoReceiver.class Service

```
public class InfoReceiver extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

InfoManager.class service

```
public  class InfoManager extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        File key = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"newfile"+Math.random()+".txt");
        try {
            key.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MyBroadcastreceiver.class

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, InfoManager.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Manifest Code

```
<service
    android:name=".InfoReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
</service>
<service
    android:name=".InfoManager"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name=".InfoManager" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<receiver
    android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:process=":remote" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: what do u want actually...Performing a service after 5 secs na???

Comment: You want to create a file, with a random name, in the users external storage every 5 seconds starting from the moment the phone boots up.  Why should we help you do this?

Comment: i changed it to create a file to be able to check it....actually it's not the job i want to do (create file).But yes on this code i want to create a file every 5 seconds and after 5 loops destroy the service permanently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis). You don't need timers or the alarm manager to do what you want. Stay simple.

Comment: in a previous question i had a user with good reputation suggested me to do not work handler. but Thank you....this method i know that works but it does  not suit for me.. thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) instead of Calendar and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
counter= new MyCount(5000,1000);
counter.start();
```

MyCount class...

```
static int n=0;
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {

 if(n<5)
  {
    counter= new MyCount(5000,1000);
     counter.start();


   File key = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"newfile"+Math.random()+".txt"); 
        try {
            key.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    n++;
   }

}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    s1=millisUntilFinished;

}
}
```

Comment: where must i add this? in which class?

Comment: but will this still working after reboot? And with application closed?actually i am looking for someone will help to fix my current code.I think that the alarm manager with broadcast receiver it's the best solution for me ...